# I have an image I created in a C# script, how do I load it into a Unity image?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I created a bitmap pixel image in some simple code in a Visual Studio WindowsFormsApplication. I want to put this image into my Unity game by replacing the stock image I have loaded into my game now. How can I script my Unity code to use this image? Preferably, I would not like to save my pixel image on my Desktop but have it directly load into my Unity game.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @XanderLuciano I ultimately would like to project this image as a holographic display on my Hololens. The image will be a graph created from data that I will be receiving that I want to project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, take the image, encode it to a `byte` array

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970062(v=vs.110).aspx

```
int width = 128;
int height = 128;
int stride = width;
byte[] pixels = new byte[height * stride];

// Define the image palette
BitmapPalette myPalette = BitmapPalettes.Halftone256;

// Creates a new empty image with the pre-defined palette

BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
    width,
    height,
    96,
    96,
    PixelFormats.Indexed8,
    myPalette,
    pixels,
    stride);

FileStream stream = new FileStream("new.png", FileMode.Create);
PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock();
myTextBlock.Text = "Codec Author is: " + encoder.CodecInfo.Author.ToString();
encoder.Interlace = PngInterlaceOption.On;
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
encoder.Save(stream);
```

Then either have it send it over a socket connection or a common file location, and load it into unity with `LoadImage`

From: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    // Load a .jpg or .png file by adding .bytes extensions to the file
    // and dragging it on the imageAsset variable.
    public TextAsset imageAsset;
    public void Start() {
        // Create a texture. Texture size does not matter, since
        // LoadImage will replace with with incoming image size.
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        tex.LoadImage(imageAsset.bytes);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
    }
}
```